# How can I tell if a given string is a valid input to PHP's preg_match?

Tags: php, pcre

I am building an admin UI where a user can manage a list PCRE strings which get passed to PHP's `preg_match` at other points in my application.

Before storing the user's input for later use by `preg_match`, I'd first like to validate that the user's input is a valid PCRE expression, otherwise later on passing it to `preg_match` throws an error.

What's the best way to validate a given string to see if it's a valid PCRE in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet will be to just pass the string to preg_match, and catch any errors that happen.

```
try{
    preg_match($in_regex, $string, $results);
    //Use $results
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Sorry, bad regex (/" . $in_regex . "/)";
}
```

[Edit]
Since that won't work, you could try:

```
function bad_regex($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    echo "Sorry, bad regex.";
}
set_error_handler("bad_regex");
preg_match($in_regex, $string, $results);
restore_error_handler();
```

Comment: I didn't think `preg_match` threw a catchable exception... let me try this. If I am wrong I feel sheepish!

Comment: in addition you can use `preg_last_error` to get more about the error

Comment: Yeah, this won't work. `preg_match` doesn't throw an exception, it causes an `E_WARNING`: `Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in - on line 4`. This will interrupt my app's saving process, since I can't catch that warning and resume.

Comment: Awesome, this works great. I am so relieved I don't need to use `popen`, that solution was a horrible thing!

Comment: I'm kind of disappointed the answer got deleted- it was incredibly clever!

Comment: Just a thought... your mini error_handler could throw an `ErrorException` on `E_WARNING` then you could use the `try ... catch` block like initially stated.